# How to fill the background of aligned blocks?

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I have the following code:

```
<div style="background-color:Aqua">
    <div style="float:left">left</div>
    <div style="float:right">right</div>
</div>
```

I want to display...

```
left                                                                        right
```

...with an aqua background, but blocks do not fill with color.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your floats, for example with `overflow: hidden`

```
<div style="background-color:Aqua; overflow: hidden">
    <div style="float:left">left</div>
    <div style="float:right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow` triggers `hasLayout` in IE7 – IE8 treats it differently

Comment: @crowjonah so what? the question wasn't how different versions of IE treating it - and it works in IE7 and IE8

Comment: Your answer doesn't work if there are absolutely positioned elements at play – I'm just trying to help the asker, and I was the first to upvote your answer, so calm down, eh?

Comment: @crowjonah sorry man.. you're right about absolutely positioned elements, but the OP didn't mention anything except 2 floated div-s in a container.. even the IE7 requirement came later in the comments..

Answer (score 0):

Float - rule for positioning depended on something, so you will never align object without that something.
So, you should use following sequence:

```
<div style="background-color:Aqua">
  <div style="float:right;max-width:50%;">Right</div><!-- 100% by default -->
  <div>Left</div>
  <div style="clear:right;"></div><!-- closing the floating -->
</div>
```

and otherwise:

```
<div style="background-color:Aqua">
  <div style="float:left;max-width:50%;">Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
  <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

or both:

```
<div style="background-color:Aqua">
  <div style="float:left;max-width:30%;">Left</div>
  <div style="float:right;max-width:30%;">Right</div>
  <div>Center</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also try to another solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using a robust clearfix, particularly this one: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/

Add this CSS:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";    
  display: block;    
  height: 0;    
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
```

and then give your containing, parent aqua div a `class="clearfix"`

Here's a [fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9rUqf/).