# Which is the correct method, inline-block or float?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a layout for a site and am confused about when to use `inline-block` or `float`. Which is the best way: `inline-block` or `float`?

Using `inline-block` means it doesn't spport Internet Explorer. Sometimes `float` is also doing damage (even using the clearfix hack).

Comment: use Table instead of CSS layout if you are really worried of IE support.

Comment: clear fix works in all cases. So, use float property as you are concerned about cross-browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Comment: Nice saying Mr_Green.Thanks!

Comment: @VIVEkUI not an answer to you question. but have you looked at _compass(sass)_ or _less_ already? it helps to create cross browser `inline-block` or `clear-fix` rules and helps with using new css features that are vendor prefixed in older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the article *[Should You Use Inline-Blocks As A Substitute For Floats](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/)*. It will help you a lot.

Answer (score -2):

For a layout, you should use neither.

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp#gsc.tab=0, all inline attributes are supported by Internet Explorer 8+, so it should be OK if you're not developing a commercial website.

I recommend using `<div>` and [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) elements such as `<header>` and `<article>`. For example,

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="myLogo.png" alt="logo"/>
    </div>
    <nav>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="pageContainer">
    <article>
      <section>
        ...
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then for individual elements in each `<div>`, you can define inline or float (like a picture or a table).

`<div>`: basically, a section of a webpage.

List of sweet HTML5 elements!: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp#gsc.tab=0

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JYZhz/

Comment: on the one hand you say that it is only ok to use `inline-block` for none commercial sites, on the other hand you recommend using html5 elements, which (if used in an IE version that doesn't support them) could break the layout more then using unsupported `inline-block`. for both html5 and inline block there are fixes to get them work in IE 6+. Additional html elements are not for layout but for semantic/logical structuring, css is for layout/styling.

Comment: true, cheers for pointing that out. Was just answering the question based on a few assumptions :)