# CSS center a textbox in a div

Tags: html, css, centering

I would like to have the same margin on top and bottom.

My container div looks like:

```
<div id="search">
    <input id="txtSearch" type="txt">
</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#search{
    min-width: 25%;
}
#txtSearch{
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

For further information please have a look at my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v6zzn53z/)

Comment: Tell me what you did ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002325/give-same-margin-to-top-and-bottom-as-margin-of-right-and-left-in-respon

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Answer (score 3):

Your `#txtSearch` selector doesn't have `margin: 0 auto` specified in the JSFiddle demo you've provided. Adding this in centralises the `input` element as it should:

```css
#txtSearch {
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/v6zzn53z/1/).

---

**Update** (from comments)

> But now the input is still on top, but there should be the same space at top and bottom.

For that I'd use a `table` display on the `header` element, and a `table-cell` display on its children, set with a `vertical-align` of "middle":

```css
#header {
    display: table;
}
#header a, #header a:link, #header a:visited, #header a:active, #header div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/v6zzn53z/2/).

Comment: Oh forgot to insert. But now the input is still on top, but there should be the same space at top and bottom.