# How to make two charts using highchart show up in the same line side by side using div

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I want to display two charts in the same line using div. Can you please help?

Here is the what I am trying but it shows up in 2 lines.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div>
        <div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; diplay:inline"></div>
        <div id="container2" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; display:inline"></div>

    </div>
```

full code in http://jsfiddle.net/nCe36/

Answer (score 9):

Just float the containers left!

Either give both `#container` and `#container2` a left float:

```
#container,
#container2 {
    float: left;
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nCe36/1/))

Or give both containers a class (say, "container") and float that class left:

```
.container {
    float: left;
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nCe36/2/))

**Edit:** `display: inline-block` will also work, as @Nile has pointed out. It's a matter of personal preference: I tend to prefer floats; some people, inline-blocks. For more information on which to use, you might want to check out this post: [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/pzqLG/