# Stop CSS floats from overflowing

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have here a code in Dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/5705036

I wanted to have these segment to stick at their position even if the browser is re-sized without using absolute positioning. Like for example, The main content container breaks a new line when the browser is re-sized [I use CSS Floats in most of my containers].

Is there something wrong with my coding?

Do floats proper for layouts ? or I need to use anything else?..

I just can't fix it by myself and by doing a lot of research ,  still,  haven't got a good idea to use it as a way to fix this. [Also, I use HTML5 tags such as: section, article, nav, etc.. ]

Comment: which segments are you talking about?

Comment: The div container that has an id of "maincontent" it drops down when I resize my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `float:left;` from `maincontent` `id` and apply a `display:table-cell;`. Your issue will be resolved.

Here is the code.

```
#maincontent {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-top: 15px;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for but I have a thing to ask, How floats and table-cell differ from each other?

Comment: I think this answer fulfills your doubts about float and table-cell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell - @JamesM.

Comment: Appreciate negative votes. Will be much appreciated if explanations are also provided.

Comment: @Nathan Lee: You don't explain your answer in no point, although this is highly adviced. Understanding floats and clearing for beginners is a hard topic. Clear explanation should be provided. (I didn't downvote, tho)

Comment: +1, can't understand the negative votes here. It probably does the job (haven't tested), is short and to the point. What else is needed?

Comment: Thnx @kleinfreund, but I kept things straight to the point relevant to his issue. So I assume he has an understanding of the things before hand, but if he does not and specifies he did not understood, I provide him with the explanation or the link that clears his doubts as I have done the same here too. Hope justfied.

Comment: Thnx @Darkzaelus. That is exactly how I do.

Comment: (not my downvote) It's a good solution, but not a good answer.

Comment: Thnx @cimmanon. Will appreciate elaboration to the point mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You should always clear parent element if You use floats inside the parent element. Your right element go down because You don't have minimal width of container, ther is sample of code:

```
#contentWrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden; /*scroll / auto it's depends on You */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your code you had a space in `<div id="contentWrapper ">` which stopped your CSS for that element from appearing. Also, you needed 2 more pixels of width on your #contentWrapper.

```
#contentWrapper {
    width: 992px;
}
```

Removing the space and changing the width of #contentWrapper worked for me. I had a quick look at the maths but haven't worked out why it needs to be 992px. Anyone?

So, in answer to your question, I'd say floats are fine and your approach is good, there were just those two minor errors.