# How do I make an image resize inside a div that is resizing to a percentage of a parent div?

Tags: css, html

The image remains in its full size and I need it to fit inside its div.

I would also like to know how I could set 2 divs side by side inside of a parent at 90% maintaining its position.

Here are:

The HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <div id="test2">
        <div id="test3">
               <div id="image"><img src="ayreon_wallpaper_the_human_equation_brain_1600.jpg" />
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
body{
background:#999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#test{
width:90%;
height:90%;
background:#1d2122;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;

margin: auto;
}
#test2{
width:90%;
height:90%;
background:#3F0;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;

margin: auto;
}
#test3{
float:left;
width:90%;
height:90%;
background:#F00;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}

#image{
float:left;
width:90%;
height:90%;
background:#F00;
background-size:100%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css selector from `#image` to `#image img`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/XFV5N/

The problem was that you were resizing the div around the image, not the image itself. By updating your CSS to style the `img` tag you solve the issue.

To set div's next to eachother, you can set them each as `display:inline; width:50%` or `float:left; width:50%`

Read more about float/inline: [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Comment: Great man, that did it and I just learned that I don't want the image to blindly follow the size of the window but instead to display the 720 or 1080 size ratio while expanding and shrinking with the window (like the VLC video player does as one resizes the window) in order to not distort the content. I am guessing that if I apply a rule to the first "div layer" and keep the subsequent ones at a percentage of it, it would always maintain the integrity of the images. What do you think?

Comment: Change the height of the image to auto and keep the width as a percentage and it should auto-scale to match the original proportions of the image, so `#image img { height: auto; }`

Comment: Justin, I did apply #image img { height: auto; } to the css, the image does keep the ratio while resizing but the div it's in brings its vertical ends to the top and bottom of the window and keeps the 90% on the sides. What I really need is for the child divs to keep their height and width at assigned percentages and therefore maintain their aspect ratio since the parent div has that condition. If only the image obeys it I won't be able to have the whole site resizing together. Thanks for the support. How do I place jpegs on the question? I believe if I could illustrate you would get it better

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but the answer may be using media queries to snap certain widths to certain dimensions. You should see an option to include an image in the toolbar when you edit your post, if not, StackOverflow may have disabled that for new users to prevent spam.