# bootstrap buttons in same line - one in a element, one in a form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons and I want them in the same line.

The buttons come one below the other because one is inside an `<a>` element and one is inside a `form`

Here is the code

```
<a href="update/"><button class="btn btn-default">Update Contact</button></a>
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete Contact</button>
</form>
```

How can I get them in the same line?

Fiddle - http://www.bootply.com/114827

Comment: Float the `a[href^="update"] button` to the `left` or `right`.

Comment: Can you give us some css or a jsfiddle? `button{display:inline-block}` could help

Comment: The `form` is also an element.  Do you know the difference between `display: block` and `display: inline`?

Comment: @CTravel Here you go - http://www.bootply.com/114827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `float:left;` on the buttons

Css:

```
button {float:left;}
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/114834)**

Comment: float is not exactly the better solution, it can have problems in more complex layouts.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy you just need to float them or put them as inline or inline block, or whatever element that contains them (that would be cleaner):

http://www.bootply.com/114841

In this particular case:

```
a, form{
  float: left;
}
```

or

```
a, form{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Read about the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11823622/463065

Answer (score 0):

Use an "inline" CSS class:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="update/">
  <button class="btn btn-default">Update Contact</button>
</a>
<form action="" method="post" class="inline">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete Contact</button>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.inline {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/114837