# Why i should use float instead display:table-cell?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am converting a PSD to html but i am little confused about float, i can use here display:table-cell; instead float for navigations, and other links. is there any standard to picking the CSS property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole host of different CSS layout strategies you can consider, and each have their own strengths and drawbacks. Floats work in every browser, down to and including IE6. Table Display only works in IE8+. It’s also not widely used because it tends to require a lot of markup to get the same effect as a simple float layout.

Most integrations require a combination of layout strategies, including absolute positioning and floats. If you aspire to be a web designer, I’d suggest you start with these.