# Floated div not taking full width

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why do floated divs don't take full width? Aren't they still block elements?

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/GKjC8/

html

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
```

css

```
div {
    background-color:cyan;
}
#a {
    float:left;
}
#b {
    clear:left;
}
```

The `a` div looks like it's `inline` since it takes as much space as its content. Can someone explain?

Comment: Because that's just what floats do. If you want the full width back, add a `width:100%` rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set width:

```
#a {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

> “You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied
>   directly to an image – which has implicit width). If no width is set,
>   the results can be unpredictable.” [Floatutorial: Float Basics](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKjC8/1/)

Comment: But why do they act like that? That's what I'm trying to understand

Answer (score 1):

That's because **float** elements behave like if a `display: inline-block` was applied to it. They expand to their content width.

As @Alek stated, if you want to set the width manually, you need to explicitly set it.

You can check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell) for more informations