# Move nav bar to the right side of div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to move my nav bar to the right side of the div wrapper. I have a Logo image in the left, and want the nav bar on the right.
When I use `float: right`, the nav bar goes right side of the div. However, every button that was horizontal goes back to vertical in the list.

See example:

[image: Example]

I've read that could correct this, with `position: relative` to parent wrapper and then `position: absolute` to the nav bar. But I'm trying to identify why the `float: right` attributes moves all the buttons vertically.

Here is my code:``

```css
.mainwidth{
   width:100%;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #0099FF;
   float:left;
   }

.mainwrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.mainwrapper img {
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.mainbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
}
.mainbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0099FF;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Agency</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
<body>
<div class=“wrapperwidth”>
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <img src="logo/holoslogo2.png" alt="Logo Holos">

  <div class="mainbar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Clients</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">CONTACTO</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://facebook.com" class="facebook">Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://twitter.com" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://youtube.com" class="youtube">Youtube</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Any insight is really appreciated!
KevinM

Comment: change **.main ul li** --> `display: block`  to  `display: inline-block`

Comment: Can you post the rest of your HTML?

Comment: Hi @APAD1, I've added the rest of HTML.

Comment: @drWisdom I've tried that as well, but still the buttons are vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636335/floated-div-not-taking-full-width

Comment: This is probably because of your logo image size, which does not leave enough space for the list items. Try giving it a fixed size, say 100px, and then see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your list items inline-block. Everything else can remain block, that's not a problem.

This works (also some margin so the links don't run into one huge word):

```
.mainbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

You also probably don't need to wrap a div around your ul. You can put the .mainbar class directly on the ul, take the ul out of your CSS, and just float that - the rest of the floats are redundant. But I digress.

Answer (score -2):

> where you want you can use in css, .mainwrapper or .mainbar

```
 margin-left:30px;
```