# When use float left and when inline-block?

Tags: html, css

In order to align two block elements I can use float left or inline-block.
Is there any advantage using inline-block?
Has it got a better performance when the page is rendered
if I use more inline-block then float commands?

HTML

```
<div class="logo"></div>
<nav >  .... </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav, .logo{

  float: left;
}
```

or

```
nav,  .logo{

  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Comment: inline-block basically turns an element into the equivalent of a `<span>`. Float will literally try to jam the element as far left as possible, even if that "rips" it away from where it normally would be drawn. The two are NOT equivalent.