# How to make the div's appear inline in the following code?

Tags: css, css-float

How to make the following div's appear inline in the following html with a scroll

@ http://jsfiddle.net/hj2E6/5/

```
  <div id="scrollable">
  <div class="childDiv">
      <div class="inner">I am the first div in first should appear inline with the rest of the text</div>
      <div class="inner">I am the second div in first should appear inline with the rest of the text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
      <div class="inner">I am the first div in Second should appear inline with the rest of the text</div>
      <div class="inner">I am the second div in Second should appear inlinewith the rest of the text </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS I have written

```
    #scrollable {
        width : 50%;
        height : 350px;
        background-color: #d0e4fe;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;

    }
    .childDiv {
        float: left;

    }
    .inner {
        float : left;
    }
```

Comment: while floating the element the `width` property required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` and `white-space:nowrap;` to make the divs appear inline and stay on the same line :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hj2E6/8/)**

[Inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) and inline elements render with a white-space between them,

> The white-space CSS property is used to to describe how whitespace
>   inside the element is handled.
>
> nowrap : Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks
>   (text wrapping) within text.

([source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space))

*CSS :*

```
#scrollable {
    width : 50%;
    height : 350px;
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.childDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.inner {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Why you have used white-space:nowrap; with the scrollable div and the first child div only.

Comment: @user1590011 added some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: So saying "display: inline" is more strict than "float:left". I  mean float : left will take up the next line if there is no more space on the current line.

Comment: @user1590011 both techniques (`display:inline-blopck;` or `float:left`)  will give you the disired layout. The difference is (mainly) that inline-block elements will render with white-space between elements, floats won't. Floats don't expand their parent size and inline/inline-block elements do. I strongly recommend you read about both properties to make a good choise depending on your use case and opinion.  you may read more about it on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify a `width` on `child element`. without specifying a width it will containing block horizontally. check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/hj2E6/16/)**.

so define a width on your class `.childDiv` and in `.inner`.

```
.childDiv 
{
float: left;
width : 50%; /*required to specify the width*/
background:red; /*just for visibility used here*/
padding:3px;
}
.inner {
float : left;
width : 50%; /*required to specify the width*/
}
```