# What causes div to move down?

Tags: html, css

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/RR2c4/6/)

```
.a,.c
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: red;
 display:inline-block;
}  
.b
{
 background-color: gray;
 display:inline-block;
 border: 1px solid;
}
.main
{
 width:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 height: 300px;
}
```

Why does the div b is at the bottom. Please set height at the fiddle and check. It ll grow down. Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: Reason for downvoting?

Comment: I request anybody to specify the reason for dwwnvoting. Because i dont find any mistakes here.

Comment: down voter's family issues, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` default value for vertical-align in CSS is baseline. You need to set the `vertical-align` property to fix that.

```
.b
{
  background-color: gray;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RR2c4/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top;` rule to `class b` or all the `classes` that have the rule `display: inline-block`. `display: inline-block` is by default **bottom aligned**.

Comment: Dear Anonymous down voter, would you care to explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Is really display:inine-block place content at the bottom? Any ref?

Answer (score 0):

you can use table-cell instead of inline-block;

```
.a,.c
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
}
.b
{
    background-color: gray;
    display:table-cell;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.main
{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/RR2c4/8/)

inline-block behave as the block level when your browser will be re-sized larger or if your contents exceeds than its width while display: table-cell; won't. You'll also find the gap between block when you apply display: inline-block;

more can be read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell) question.

> question

Answer (score 0):

There are rules in display: in-line block that mess it up in your case. Just change them to float: left as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RR2c4/11/)

```
.a,.c
{
width: 100px;
height: 300px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}

.b
{
background-color: gray;
float: left;
border: 1px solid;
 }

.main
{
width:100%;
float: left;
height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any contents on first and last divs.

Because all the divs are displayed `inline-block` the default position will go to baseline. Try adding some contents to the `.a` and `.c` divs, you will see different behaviors.

When you are all setup with the contents you need to adjust the `vertical-align` to have your desired look.