# Why isn't the div coloring the full height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Edit: Plunker preview here - http://embed.plnkr.co/2afyRrde2rxncxPelB69/preview

---

Probably a terrible title but after a minute I haven't been able to come up with better.

I have created a simple page with angularjs and some html. The issue I'm having is actually with css. When you click on a menu item, it highlights the block, but I'm getting a weird 1-2 px border that isn't highlighted along the bottom.

Been at this for hours and seriously going up the wall with it...

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

<!--AngularJS code-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>


<!-- Adding the ng-app declaration to initialize AngularJS -->
<div id="main" ng-app>
    <!-- The navigation menu will get the value of the "active" variable as a class.
         The $event.preventDefault() stops the page from jumping when a link is clicked. -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h3 class="pull-left company-heading">Tool Title</h3>
        </div>
        <nav class="pull-right {{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">

            <!-- When a link in the menu is clicked, we set the active variable -->

            <a href="#" class="home" ng-click="active='home'">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="projects" ng-click="active='projects'">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="services" ng-click="active='services'">Services</a>
            <a href="#" class="contact" ng-click="active='contact'">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- ng-show will show an element if the value in the quotes is truthful,
         while ng-hide does the opposite. Because the active variable is not set
         initially, this will cause the first paragraph to be visible. -->

    <p ng-hide="active">Please click a menu item</p>
    <p ng-show="active">You chose <b>{{active}}</b></p>
</div>
fd
</body>

</html>
```

My css:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    font:15px/1.3 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #5e5b64;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #185A82;
    margin-bottom:45px;
    line-height: normal;    
}

#title {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 18px 200px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;

}

a, a:visited {
    outline:none;
    color:#389dc1;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

section, footer, header, aside, nav{
    display: block;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}


/*-------------------------
    The menu
--------------------------*/

nav{
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:2px;

}

nav a{
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 18px 30px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.25s;
    transition:background-color 0.25s;
}

nav a:first-child{
    border-radius:2px 0 0 2px;
}

nav a:last-child{
    border-radius:0 2px 2px 0;
}

nav.home .home,
nav.projects .projects,
nav.services .services,
nav.contact .contact{
    background-color:#e35885;
}

p{
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#7d9098;
}

p b{
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background-color:#c4d7e0;
    border-radius:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: please try to reproduce your problem on http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Thanks, done so here: http://embed.plnkr.co/2afyRrde2rxncxPelB69/preview

Comment: You are using two different methods of displaying elements next to each other. Either use floats and clear, or use display inline. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Answer (score 5):

You can try to add on your a tags the following css

```
line-height: 60px;/*height of your header*/
padding: 0px 30px;/*remove the top and bottom padding*/
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 3):

Update the below css values with:

```
nav a{
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  text-decoration:none !important;
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.25s;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.25s;
  transition:background-color 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: That makes the blue bar smaller, but now the pink is slightly too tall. Is there some elegant solution by which I can make the highlight fill the height of the bar?

Comment: In that case increase the padding value of anchor tag by nav a{22px 30px}

Comment: Thanks for the follow up response. With this I see the exact same thing, it seems to be ever so slightly beyond the blue bar.

Comment: It works fine @ my chrome browser, you can use firebug(firefox) or inspect element in chrome to match the padding values as per your requirement.

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly what I am using. Perhaps my eyes deceive me.

Comment: As you were the first person to posit this solution, I will certainly select your answer as "correct" if this is what I end up using. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Your titles padding is the problem

This will work:

```
#title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 200px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have come up with the same solution as Akwebmedia. First, how are you two calculating 14 (or is it just guess/check)? Second, it still overflows a bit, see my response to Akwebmedia.

Comment: sorry was too late, well adjust the padding of the links then:
padding: 22px 30px;

Answer (score 2):

Update your css style of `nav > a` with this:

```
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 23px 30px 19px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    transition: background-color 0.25s; 
}
```

Otherwise you can set a custom height to the `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to adjust the size of the elements by using padding can be tricky. In this case it is better that the size is determined by the content of the elements. I propose the following changes:

First remove the padding of `#tittle` and instead add the desired positioning.

```
#title {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 200px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

For the height of `#header` match the height of the child elements, we must include an element with style `clear: both`. This is so because `#nav` has `float: right` and the floats algorithm will extract the box from the normal flow. (reference: [Visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) )

HTML:

```
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">...</div>
    <nav class="pull-right {{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">...</nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    ...
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Finally, the elements contained in `#header` that we do not want in the normal flow are include in a div with the style `float: left`.

I updated your example:
http://embed.plnkr.co/ekxYOXLp4UUZD7ikHMHM/preview

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you use floats, you need to add a "clear" style to clear the floats:

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

This is because anything inside of a div that's floated does not take space inside the div.  The clear float CSS instructs the DIV to ensure that it encloses its floated children.

For example:

```
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <h3 class="pull-left company-heading">Tool Title</h3>
    </div>
    <nav class="pull-right {{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
      <!-- When a link in the menu is clicked, we set the active variable -->
      <a href="#" class="home" ng-click="active='home'">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="projects" ng-click="active='projects'">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="services" ng-click="active='services'">Services</a>
      <a href="#" class="contact" ng-click="active='contact'">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <br style="clear:both" />
  </div>
```

You also have to remove the margin-bottom CSS style for your header.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #185A82;

    line-height: normal;    
}
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWXU1tQFHv108Y1ow0V2?p=preview)

Comment: This actually makes the visible gap under the highlighted block even bigger :-/

Comment: You also have to remove the margin-bottom CSS style that you have in your #header.

Answer (score 1):

Change the padding of nav a to

```
nav a {
    padding: 21.5px 30px;
}
```