# How do I use nth:child selector with the each function for json of jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flickr Feed</title>
    <link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .image {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            border: solid 1px rgb(27,45,94);
            background-color: white;
            margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
        }
        .image:hover {
            border-color: red;
            background-color: rgb(204,204,204); 
        }

        img{
            max-width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            display: block;
        }

        header{
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
            var searchInfo = {
                id : "113158794@N07",
                format : "json"
            }

            $.getJSON(url,searchInfo,function(data){
                $("h1").text(data.title);
                var photoHTML = '';
                $.each(data.items,function(i,photo){
                    photoHTML += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">';
                    photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link +'">';
                    photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m','_s') + '">';
                    photoHTML += '<p>' + photo.title + '</p></a></div>';
                });
                $('#photos').append(photoHTML);
            }); 
        }); // end ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">&amp;</span> jQUERY: THE&nbsp;MISSING&nbsp;MANUAL
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Flickr Images</h1>
                <div id="photos"></div>
                <br class="clearLeft">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I like to use a nth:child selector so on the ($.getJSON(url,searchInfo,function(data){ ) part I can clear the float sometime.

Comment: What is your actual question? Lorem ipsum because you do not have enough details.... add more details then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

w3schools says

> :nth-child(2) Selector: Specify rules for every element that is the second child of its parent:

so if you use a generic selector based on the image container

```
.imageContainer .images:nth-child(3){clear:left;}
```

Then you should probably be able to apply your css rules without using any javascript.

Though, just to focus on the problem and not the solution, you really just wanted a way to select every X image. And for that, you first need the index of your current position in the .each loop, which you already have at the "i" right before the photo-variable.

```
$.each(data.items,function(i,photo){
```

now we use the "%" modular operator to calculate if this current index is, for example, a "third" index (3, 6 ,9 12, 15 ...) and get an if-test that you can place where you need it inside the .each() loop.

```
    if(i % 3 == 0){
      //do stuff, like add a particular class
      photoHTML += '<a class="particularClass" href="' + photo.link +'">';
    }
```

**Edit!** If you are adding images dynamically after the initial page load, then checking the index in the .each() loop wont yield wanted results. I suggest changing the if-check  to

```
 if(i % Document.getElementsByClassName('images').length == 0)
```

To test against the total amount of images, which then includes the ones already existing. This ofcourse only works if there's only one place you use the class 'images'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear in HTML directly, you can style current HTML.

```
#photos > div:nth-child(3n):after {content: ''; display: block; clear: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using float:left may not work in some browsers, display:inline-block is more practicable. You must read this post: [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

If you gonna use display:inline-block you dont need any nth-child methods.