# Auto re-sizing div with text-area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following simple markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <textarea id="content" />
</div>
```

I need to set the min-width of the `div` is large enough to wrap the entire textarea when we start to re-sizing the textarea. How can I do that? I hope this is a very typicall problem but I just haven't come across that. JS or pure CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have to do is to set min-width to textarea element and to set container to have inline-block property

```
#container{
    display: inline-block;
}

#container textarea {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set `float:left` on the div:

```
#container {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wre0mcx9/)

Comment: Real magic, thank you. Couldn't you explain why floating left make it working? I really don't understand.

Comment: Float left is 'trick' here more than real solution. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Comment: @DženanKlapuh Maybe you 're right. But would you mind explaining your solution then. I checked it and it worked.

Comment: @user3663882 In css one element always fill the surrounding element but when you create div the width is always 100%. If you set `float: left` the same as `display:inline` the element will shrink and be the size of the thing that's inside.

Comment: Every element or wrapper that doesn't have exact size ( width or height ) should have display set to inline or inline block. Otherwise that element will have 0px height/width. If you set display: inline-block ( in this case ) container will stretch as the content stretch. This apply to anything from pure text to forms.

If you set that your container is 100% width and haven't specified height. Your content of the container will stretch in height but your container won't follow it because none of the display properties are not set - In other words it will be 0 in height.