# How to horizontally align div element to another div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position

I create the following HTML page and I would align the two DIV elements (the ones with `lista` and `scheda` id, contained within `parent` div) to the same position, at the top of the page. Here is my code:

```css
#tabella1,
#tabella1 td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
th {
  border: solid 1px;
  font-style: bold;
  background-color: white;
}
#tabella1 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gray;
}
#tabella1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#tabella1 tr:nth-child(n):not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.titolo {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#lista {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
#msg {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#scheda {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#tabella2 td:nth-child(even) {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.cellaVuota {
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="carica">
  <form method="post" action="carica2.php">
    <label for "n">Inserisci nome:
      <input type="text" id="n" name="nome" size="10" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Invia</button>
  </form>
  <form method="post" action="carica2.php">
    <button type="submit" name="logout">Logout</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="lista">
    <table id="tabella1">
      <tr>
        <th>Modello</th>
        <th>27.5</th>
        <th>29</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Riga 1</td>
        <td>Riga 2</td>
        <td>Riga 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="titolo">Bici Mountain Bike</p>
  </div>
  <div id="scheda">
    <p class="titolo">Bici selezionata</p>
    <table id="tabella2">
      <tr>
        <td>Modello</td>
        <td class="cellaVuota"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Misura 27.5</td>
        <td class="cellaVuota"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Misura 29</td>
        <td class="cellaVuota"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I searched and searched here before post this question (see `position` and ~top` properties in the CSS code), but I do not figure out how to reach my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to both divs.
You can also remove `position: relative;` and `top: 0;` properties

Comment: You can also use 'float: left' instead of 'display: inline-block'. Then you don't need 'vertical-align. However I would recommend to use inline-block. Read more about differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell