# How can I fix the div to the bottom of the bigger div?

Tags: css

I am creating a simple css chart responsive that works on any browser.
This is my code:

```html
<div style="width:500px;height:300px;">
    <div style="width:10%;height:20%;background:#00ffff;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width:10%;height:40%;background:#00ffff;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width:10%;height:80%;background:#00ffff;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, the chart is inverted:

http://jsfiddle.net/xkd6twsq/

I tried with:

```
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
```

but doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/xkd6twsq/1/

Comment: I've updated my answer below. The main idea with `display: inline-block` stays, I've added vertical alignment to bottom of parent which I forgot before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`. The parent needs `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align` to align graph to bottom.

```
<style>
    div {
        display: table-cell; 
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    div div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10%;
        background: #0ff;
    }
</style>

<div style="width:500px;height:300px;">
    <div style="height:20%;"></div>
    <div style="height:40%;"></div>
    <div style="height:80%;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xkd6twsq/4/

Comment: @xRobot: you can simply try it. But yes, it works in all browsers supported `table-cell`, IE8+.

Comment: I haven't IE8+ to try :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `float:left`, using `display: inline-block` will get what you want:

```html
<div style="width:500px;height:300px;">
<div style="width:10%;height:20%;background:#00ffff;display:inline-block;"></div>
<div style="width:10%;height:40%;background:#00ffff;display:inline-block;"></div>
<div style="width:10%;height:80%;background:#00ffff;display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

[All about floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) from CSS-tricks explains when to use floats and [this `display` types answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11823622/1326147) details why floats are not the best option.