# Display three blocks inline CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have three `div`'s, `#left_sidebar`, `#records_list` and `#right_sidebar`, I want to display them inline, but when I using `display:inline-block`, all seems to be fine but sidebars placing on the bootom of page, then I try to use `float`, but still getting some creppy behavior, then I do this:

```
#left_sidebar {
    top: 0px;
    width: 142px;
    float: left;
}

#records_list {
    width: 530px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right_sidebar {
    background-image: url('../images/enstein_banner.png');
    width: 174px;
   height: 231px;   
   float: right;
}
```

(you see mix from `float`'s and `display`), and all works fine, so can somebody explain me, if it right? Or I need do this somehow else? Thanks!

P.S. If you need more info, or it a little bit unclearly what I am asking just say, and I will try to improve question.

Comment: please add float:left to each and then check it work for you or not

Comment: Could you create a demo with your HTML and CSS please, that was we can have a look at what is going on.

Comment: @priya786, it works for now, thanks! but I cant get why it doesnt work when I try this at the begining of process... since you give me proper answet first, you can post answer and I will accept it..

Comment: I will post answer so,Please now check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#left_sidebar {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  color: #fff;
}
#records_list {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  color: #fff;
}
#right_sidebar {
  background-image: url('../images/enstein_banner.png');
  width: 15%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  height: 231px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left_sidebar">left bar</div>
  <div id="records_list">center part</div>
  <div id="right_sidebar">right bar</div>
</div>
```

Please now check this

Answer (score 0):

Since all the three `div` have fixed width, you need a wrapping `div` width fixed width.

And gave `float:left` instead of `inline-block`

Check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/racnob3f/

Answer (score 0):

I know you know about the concepts of float, i think you need more clarification, There is a good discussion about the float, inline, inline-block here please refer
[float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Answer (score 0):

give float left to all blokes, float means that they will become inline
and they will displayed one after another 
if you want to add space between them with margin

make changes like this:

```
#left_sidebar {
width: 142px;
float: left;
}

#records_list {
width: 530px;
float: left;
}

#right_sidebar {
background-image: url('../images/enstein_banner.png');
width: 174px;
height: 231px;   
float: left;
}
```