# Div's not sitting beside each other inside a wrap

Tags: css

I've got two images that I want to sit beside each other inside the parent div but I can't get them to do it.

```
.column {width:100%;max-width:1500px; margin:0 auto; }

.span_1_of_2 {width:50%; display:inline-block; }

.span_2_of_2 {width:50%;display:inline-block; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/87xzwj5t/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's white-space that's doing you in.

Add this CSS:

```
.column { font-size: 0; }
.column > div { font-size: 1rem; /* Or whatever you want it to be */ }
```

and it'll fix your problem.

The `font-size: 0` makes sure the white-space isn't rendered, and then the `font-size: 1rem` resets the font in the child divs to whatever it was set at document root (this is by default 16px in most browsers).

Inline-block elements display just like elements in text flow, which is why the white-space is respected when they're rendered.

## <kbd>[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/87xzwj5t/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespace in html, i will work

```css
.column {width:100%;max-width:1500px; margin:0 auto; }

.span_1_of_2 {width:50%; display:inline-block; }

.span_2_of_2 {width:50%;display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="column">
<div class="span_1_of_2">Div 1</div><div class="span_2_of_2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `display:inline-block` adds about `4px`of margin to the div with it because of the whitespace. If you still want to use it, you could do something like this:

```
.span_2_of_2 {width:50%; display:inline-block; margin-left:-4px; }
```

**EDIT**

What Josh said may be true. Why don't you just float them? Like this:

```
    .span_1_of_2 {width:50%;float:left; }
    .span_2_of_2 {width:50%;float:left; }
```

Then of course clear the float.

Comment: That'll only work for very specific font-sizes, namely those whose white-space takes up `4px`.

Comment: Not all browsers calculate the white-space exactly the same.  So the `margin-left:-4px` is more dangerous that is `float:left`

Comment: Thank you guys for explaining this. I now know that it is not a good solution for the whitespace issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left;` to the first `span`

**CSS**

```
.span_1_of_2 {
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

> Here's the deal: a series of inline-block elements formatted like you
>   normally format HTML will have spaces in between them. That´s why with two span and the gap between them you will have more than 100%.

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/87xzwj5t/2/)**

Comment: You shouldn't use display:inline-block and float on the same div

Comment: @EricCicero ... what are you saying is a complete mistake... Why we can not use inline-block and float in the same div?

Comment: Don't be angry man. Just read any article that compares the two. They never use them in tandem. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Comment: Another example: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/ . Since they do the same thing essentially, why would you use both at the same time? That's not best practices.

Comment: Yeah..i know this articles...but by W3C there is no mistakes.. you can use both and they are valid

Comment: Ok but why do it the less efficient way that involves more markup?

Comment: But you don't need it!! I'm sorry man let's agree to disagree

Comment: @LuisP.A., have a look on https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo: floats, absolutely positionned and fixed elements are almost always `block`s. `display` property generally doesn't influence them.