# Why doesn't work clear:both?

Tags: html, css

Here I was expecting `count` to move down below each `*ID` classe, but it doesn't happen. Each `*ID` and its corresponding `count` are in the same line. How do I fix this and why wasn't it getting cleared?

```
<div class="statusInfo">
  <div class="Scribbles">
    <div class="ScribblesID">Scribbles</div>
    <div class="count">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Following">
    <div class="FollowingID">Following</div>
    <div class="count">100</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Followers">
    <div class="FollowersID">Followers</div>
    <div class="count">100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.statusInfo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
}
.Scribbles {
  float: left;
}
.Following {
  float: left;
}
.Followers {
  float: left;
}
.ScribblesID {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.FollowingID {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.FollowersID {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.count {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Float property doesn't work with inline/inline-block property of display. If you are using inline-block then it creates block element in same line, so you don't need float.

Comment: @ali Float works just fine on inline/inline-block.

Comment: `clear: both` must be applied to an element after all the floats, not inside one. You can also get the same effect by applying `overflow: auto` to the container (.statusInfo).

Comment: @JimCote: But inside 2 elements are there, first one float:left and next clear. So this should work, right?

Comment: @Rob: when you use float then you element is no more inline element. After using float it is block element, you can avoid using inline and float together. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clear property only works on block level elements. You are using inline-block and `clear:both;` won't apply to that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear