# How to get panels/classes side by side in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the problem I am having:

[How my page looks on firefox](http://image.prntscr.com/image/aa67496744514c4ba96048097daeeca9.png)

and [How my page looks on chrome](http://prnt.sc/exxyf0)

What I want to do is get reserve form and data source forms side by side. I have already set a class using the fieldset method but can't figure out what to use to have it side by side.

Using this for data sources form

```
 .tables
 {
    width:372px;
     border-color:Black;
     margin-left:150px;
     height:500px;
 }
```

and using this for Reserve Form

```
 .mreg
 {

     width:372px;
     border-color:Black;
     margin-left:150px;
     height:500px;
 }
```

Just want two get the two forms side by side.

Edit -

Asp.net coding for Reserve Form:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblerrormsg" runat="server" Text="Error Message" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<fieldset class="mreg">
<legend>Reserve </legend>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Reserve ID" Font-Bold=true></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRID" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>
     <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtLID" ErrorMessage="Loan ID Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
        <br />
            <br />

<br />
        </fieldset>
```

Coding for data source form:

```
fieldset class="tables">
<legend>Data Sources </legend>
  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Reservation Table" Font-Bold=true></asp:Label>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        DataKeyNames="Reservation_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderStyle="Dotted">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
          </fieldset>

</asp:Content>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should give `float:left` to float to the left of screen and get side by side. Also it is not a good practice to give width as `px` as screen sizes vary.

```
.tables
 {
     width:48%;
     border-color:Black;
     float:left;
     display:block;
     height:500px;
 }

 .mreg
 {

     width:48%;
     border-color:Black;
     float:left;
     display:block
     height:500px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple css options that you could use.  As one:

```
float:left;
```

...will allow the divs to effectively "float" to the left side of their container, which will solve your problem.  However, floats are problematic for a number of reasons, and there are often better options.  For example, you can consider taking advantage of the "display" css property, such as:

```
display: inline-block;
```

This would also display your divs in a horizontal fashion, and tends to behave more consistently and with fewer problems.  There are more options for the "display" property, though, which is worth looking into -- a good overview of some of the options can be found here:

[float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Comment: I just tried your code and on firefox it shows like this http://prntscr.com/exyhf9

Comment: Just updated my asp.net coding for my forms is there maybe something wrong there?