# spans display:inline-block; how to remove white space

Tags: html, css

I found this question [How do I get rid of white spaces between spans without manipulating the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235151/how-do-i-get-rid-of-white-spaces-between-spans-without-manipulating-the-html)

where the seccond answer (talking about `white-space:collapse;` and `white-space-collapse: discard;`) would be nice. Now that answer is almost two years old and `white-space:collapse;` still doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to remove the white spaces from the `<span>`without using `float:left;` AND without writing all `<span>`s on one line?

[Here is a fiddle with the spans and the white space](http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/)

```
<div class="col">
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
    <span class="field orange"></span>
</div>
```

What I don't want is this:

```
<div class="col"><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One problem that arrises when you use inline-block is that whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen.  Gross.  There are a few ways to remove that space;  some of them are just as gross, one is reasonably nicer:

**First:**
The only 100% solution to this issue is to not put whitespace between those elements in the HTML source code:

```
<div class="col"><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span><span class="field orange"></span></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/6/)

**Second:**
The best white-space solution is to set a font-size of 0 on the parent to the inline block elements. you'd do this:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0px; font-size: 0;}
.field {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;height:20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/1/)

**Third:**
This solution is a bit gangsta but also works.  Using HTML comments as spacers between the elements works just as placing no space between elements would:

```
<div class="col">
    <span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
 --><span class="field orange"></span>
</div>
```

**Fourth** soution:

```
.field  {
    margin-left: -4px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;height:20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Fifth** solution:
This solution is to simply place the closing > next to the start of the next tag:

```
<div class="col">
    <span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
</div>
```

Comment: To your second solution I would do `.col{font-size: 0;}` over `*{font-size: 0;}`.

Comment: another solution is using script to remove all the empty TextNodes of the parent, but we may not have to use that solution.

Comment: @KingKing how would that be looking like?

Comment: @caramba demo here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ce82e/15/ using pure Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your HTML, the best solution I have is to set `font-size:0` for the container and set a font-size for the spans.
Here is your **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/ce82e/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

One solution, that I adopt, is to comment out the whitespace

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/2/

```
<div class="col">
        <span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span><!--
     --><span class="field orange"></span>
</div>
```

Another solution, just so you know your options, is to put the closing tag on the line below

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/9/

```
<div class="col">
    <span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span
    ><span class="field orange"></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
           <span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green">
    </span><span class="field green"></span>
</div>
```

A javascript solution would be

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ce82e/16/

```
$.fn.removeSpace = function(){ 
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; 
  }).remove();
};

// Then Calling it

$('.col').removeSpace();
```