# using two spans inside a paragraph adds a space

Tags: html, css

I a got a weird situation and I can not figure out why this is happening. I have the following simple situation:

```
<p>
  <span class="bold">N</span>
  <span class="bold">ote</span>
</p>
```

With the following CSS class:

```
.bold{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

When I run this code I will get the following output: **N ote**.

I find this pretty weird because whenever I use the following HTML code:

```
<p>
  <span class="bold">N</span><span class="bold">ote</span>
</p>
```

The output will be: **Note**

Now I am curious what is causing this effect?

Comment: In the first example you have a newline that counts as a whitespace, and inline elements take that into consideration thus adding a gap between the words.
Similar to this problem: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: And also [How do I get rid of white spaces between spans without manipulating the HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235151/how-do-i-get-rid-of-white-spaces-between-spans-without-manipulating-the-html)

Answer (score 0):

Line break is causing a space space/tab/enter all will create a space in inline tags. I think.

Comment: You should post this as a comment. Especially if you're not sure about something :-)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I don't have enough reputation to post as comment to the main thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

1)make all spans at the same line and it should solve it.if that dose not work try number 2.

2)
      span{
        margin:0;padding:0;
      }

Answer (score -1):

The other way around to do it is

```
.bold{
      font-weight:bold;
 }
span.bold:after{
    content:"ote";
 }
```

CSS tricks has partially solved the problem but it may not work if you format your HTML code.